# Extract 2 colums out of a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a very simple Problem I guess.

I have loaded an csv file into python of the form:

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 18.07.2018 | 12:00 AM |
| 18.07.2018 | 12:30 AM |
| ... | ... |
| 19.07.2018 | 12:00 AM |
| 19.07.2018 | 12:30 AM |
| ... | ... |

I basically just want to extract all rows with the Date 18.07.2018 and the single one from 19.07.2018 at 12:00 AM to calculate some statistical measures from the Data.

My current Code (Klimadaten is the Name of the Dataframe):

```
Klimadaten = pd.read_csv ("Klimadaten_18-20-July.csv")
Day_1 = Klimadaten[Klimadaten.Date == "18.07.2018"]
```

I guess it could be solved with something like an if statment?

I have just a very basic knowledge of python but im willing to learn the necessary steps. I'm currently doing my Bachelorthesis with simulated climate Data, and I will have to perform statistical Tests and work with a lot of Data, so maybe someone also could tell me in what concepts I should look further in (I have access to an online Python course but will not have the time to watch all lessons)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to take only the data that is there on the date 18.07.2018. The example I wrote to you below writes the date only if it is equal to 18.07.2018, but by changing the row and the columns ( you can search on an entire column or on an entire line (depends on your excel).

```
for i in range(len(Klimadaten)):
date = df.values[i][0]
if date == "18.07.2018":
    print(date)
    element = df.values[i][1]
    print(element)
```

Hope i was helpful

Comment: this is kinda inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Klimadaten = pd.read_csv ("Klimadaten_18-20-July.csv")
Day_1 = Klimadaten[Klimadaten.Date == "18.07.2018" | (Klimadaten.Date == "18.07.2018" & Klimadaten.Time == "12:00 AM")]

basically what it means is: bring me all the rows that date is 18.07.2018 OR (date is 19.07.2018 AND time is 12:00 AM)" so you can construct more complex queries like that :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if you understood my Problem. I want all rows from 18.07.2018 
 and also the single value from 19.07.2018 at 12:00 AM. So maybe more something like the following (the code gives an error):
Day_1 = Klimadaten[(Klimadaten.Date == "18.07.2018") | (Klimadaten.Date == "19.07.2018" & Klimadaten.Time == "12:00 AM")] 

I'm also not understanding this sign here in the code you wrote: "|". I didn't find what it means in a quick search. Your code gives the error "Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]"

Answer (score 0):

With help of the the [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html) I figured out the right syntax for my problem:

```
Day_1 = Klimadaten[(Klimadaten["Date"] == "18.07.2018") | (Klimadaten["Date"] == "19.07.2018") & (Klimadaten["Time"] == "12:00:00 AM")]
```